# MySQL Update with distincted Join

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `tmp1` (
    `c1` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `c2` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `tmp2` (
    `c1` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `c2` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);
```

c2 is Primary key.
And i have values like this for tmp1:

```
|| 1 || val1 ||
|| 2 || val2 ||
|| 2 || val3 ||
```

for tmp2:

```
|| 1 || val11 ||
|| 2 || val22 ||
|| 2 || val33 ||
|| 2 || val44 ||
```

I need to update tmp2 by joining c1 field to receive result like this:

```
|| 1 || val1 ||
|| 2 || val2 ||
|| 2 || val3 ||
|| 2 || val44 ||
```

When i use regular inner join i'll receive wrong result:

```
|| 1 || val1 ||
|| 2 || val2 ||
|| 2 || *val2* ||
|| 2 || *val2* ||
```

I need join for update like this:

```
|| 1 || val1 ||  ->(by c1)  || 1 || val11 ||
|| 2 || val2 ||  ->(by c1)  || 2 || val22 ||
|| 2 || val3 ||  ->(by c1)  || 2 || val33 ||
```

or like this (i think maybe is more real)

```
|| 1 || val1 ||  ->(by c1)  || 1 || val11 ||
|| 2 || val2 ||  ->(by c1)  || 2 || val22 ||
```

So in second case i think i need to group tmp2 by c1, group tmp1 by c1 and then update only one row in that group.

This select returns what i need to update:

```
select tmp1.c2, tmp2.c2 from tmp1
inner join tmp2 on tmp1.c1 = tmp2.c1 
group by tmp2.c1

|| val1 || val11 ||
|| val2 || val22 ||
```

Comment: When the first column in `tmp2` is the same, how is it supposed to know which row from `tmp1` it should copy? You need some way of distinguishing the rows.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. MySQL is returning the right result according to SQL standards (though without the exact query it's hard to say)

Comment: I think that update must be something like this. But it's wrong sql:UPDATE tmp2 as up 
set up.c2 = (select tmp1.c2 from tmp1
inner join tmp2 as j on tmp1.c1 = j.c1 where up.c1 = tmp1.c1
group by j.c1)

Comment: This is also wrong query =(     UPDATE tmp2 as up
JOIN (select ij.c2 as x, src.c2 as y from tmp1 as src
inner join tmp2 as ij on src.c1 = ij.c1 
group by src.c1) ON up.c2 = x
SET up.c2 = y

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem with this query:

```
UPDATE tmp2 as up
JOIN (select ij.c2 as x, src.c2 as y from tmp1 as src
inner join tmp2 as ij on src.c1 = ij.c1 
group by src.c1) as sel ON up.c2 = sel.x
SET up.c2 = y
```